# Unable to connect to SMTP server

Tags: java, smtp, jakarta-mail

I am trying to connect to the SMTP server from my java application. Getting the below error

```
 Could not connect to SMTP host: w.x.y.z , port: 25, response: -1
```

This is on a windows machine. When i telnet to the same, it is successful.

I tried to send the mail from another linux machine in the same network, it was sent successful.

Could some one guide me if i need to do any changes on the windows machine to get it working?

I am trying the application on Windows 8.1.

Comment: Please post some code as to what you tried

Comment: Also if there is any exception stack trace that goes with this error that may help to post as well.

Answer (score 0):

I got the issue resolved. I needed to ask my network team to allow my machine IP to connect to the SMTP server.